# Research Gate gathering data

Tags: journals, legal-issues, social-media

Does anybody know how ResearchGate gather data? I just clicked on a scientific paper in my browser (not through Research Gate), and in less than an hour I had received an e-mail notification that the author of my recent read is on ResearchGate. Is this legal?

Comment: You probably downloaded the paper from ResearchGate directly, because sometimes the Google scholar points to the ResearchGate copy of the paper.

Comment: No, I read it directly on the ScienceDirect and I was even not googling it. That is why it is surprising for me.

Comment: Do you have a researchgate account? If yes, you clicked through the terms and conditions and you probably have agreed to them knowing every time you bat an eye.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the proprietary mechanisms behind a particular commercial site, and thus both not publicly disclosed and likely to change without notice.